# REPETIR UNA CONDICION EN UN CICLO WHILE DENTRO DE UNA FUNCION

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Me encuentro ante el siguiente condigo que cree:

```
function numeros_aleatorios2(minimo, maximo){
let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximo - minimo) + minimo)
let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximo - minimo) + minimo)
if (num1 === num2){
    return `¡Las maquinas se han puesto de acuerdo! 1° num: ${num1}, 2° num: ${num2} `
}else{
    return `¡Las maquinas no coinciden: 1° num: ${num1}, 2° num: ${num2} `
}
}
console.log(numeros_aleatorios2(1,10))
```

Dada la funcion y la forma en que está expresada, al darle por parametro un rango, las "maquinas" generan un numero aleatorio, que posteriormente la condicion del if/else evalua para determinar si han coincidido o no lo han hecho.

El problema que tengo aquí es que de esta forma planteado, solo realiza una unica vez la comprobacion. Como no tengo forma de saber cuantas veces debe repetirse el codigo hasta que los numeros elegido coincidan, entiendo que debo usar un ciclo while, pero entiendo de que manera realizarlo daod que he trabajado en mi estudio principalmente con ciclos for.

Si me pudieran explicar esto seria de gran ayuda para mi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ciclo while funciona de manera que según la condición o el valor booleano que estés manejando como parámetro, el ciclo va a correrse hasta que esta condicional no se cumpla, si la condicional desde el inicio no se cumple no va a correr ninguna vez; para esto existe doWhile que funciona de la misma forma, pero corre al menos una vez.
Lo que hice en tu código fue modificar la función números aleatorios para que regrese un booleano, para saber si el número se encontró o no, y en el while puse una condicional, para que cuando el número sea el mismo; salgamos del while, además de agregar una variable numérica para llevar una cuenta de cuántas veces corre el código, espero te sirva

```js
function numeros_aleatorios2(minimo, maximo){
  let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximo - minimo) + minimo)
  let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximo - minimo) + minimo)
  if (num1 === num2){
        console.log(`¡Las maquinas se han puesto de acuerdo! 1° num: ${num1}, 2° num: ${num2} `)
    return true
  }else{
        console.log(`¡Las maquinas no coinciden: 1° num: ${num1}, 2° num: ${num2} `)
    return false
  }
}

var numbersMatch = false
var amountOfLoops = 0

while(!numbersMatch){
    amountOfLoops++
  numbersMatch = numeros_aleatorios2(1, 10)
}

console.log(`El ciclo ha corrido ${amountOfLoops} veces`)
```

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS! increible tu rta, super clara y concisa. y mi otra pregunta era: ¿cómo hago para contar cuantas veces corrieron las maquinas hasta poderse de acuerdo? y justo lo agregaste, muchas gracias Jorge!